# Zebra rw420 error android bluetooth Xperia U

Tags: zebra-printers

I have a printer RW420 and Zsdk'm using to print it, since I configured the Pin through the zebra setup utilities more when I try to open a connection to it through the mac adress running through a software android 4 it opens the screen asking pin twice and can not make the connection in the eclipse logcat returns bluez.Error.AlreadyExists and then a second error connectionAttemptFailed (host is down). Anyone ever managed to perform printing with this printer and android? There's something different to do? Used Zsdk or classes for native communication of android?

The code I tested was this:

```
MacAdd String = "00037A67EF08";
BluetoothPrinterConnection myConn = new BluetoothPrinterConnection (macAdd);
PrinterCommandImpl cmdGetFirmware PrinterCommandImpl = new ("! U1 getvar \" appl.name \           "\ r \ n");

try {

    / / Open connection to printer. This requires que
    / / The devices already be paired.
    myConn.open ();

    / / Send command to printer and wait for 8000 ms response
    byte [] response = cmdGetFirmware.sendAndWaitForResponse (myConn, 8000, 200);

    / / Display the responses in a TextView
    / / Status.setText (new String (response));
    String s = new String (response);

    / / Close connection
    myConn.close ();
} Catch (Exception ex) {
  / / Catch error here
}
```

Anything can help, since I am with this problem for a week and can not get out of the place!! Maybe a code example that actually works.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

While this isn't necessarily a programming answer, Zebra printers with older firmware have a handful of Bluetooth inconsistencies.  It might be worth checking the printer's firmware and making sure it is up to date.  You will need to know the PCC number of your printer (should be on the label on the bottom of the printer) to determine which firmware you need.

www.zebra.com/firmware

There is also a free app on the Android market called "Zebra Utilities" that is meant to help demonstrate the Zebra SDK functionality.  You may want to download the app to see if it can communicate with the RW 420.